# delphi MS Office outlook error

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole

I am trying to send a mail through my application developed in BDS 2006 via MS office Outlook.
It works totally fine with my outlook running ,but it fails in the `try` block if outlook is closed.

It displays error `EOlesystem error : Operation unavailable` and does not go to `Except`block

my code

```
 procedure TMyform.BTN_mailClick(Sender: TObject);
 const
    olMailItem =0;
 var
    Outlook: OleVariant;
    vMailItem: variant;
 begin
  try
   Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
   Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;
  vMailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
  vMailItem.Recipients.Add(mailaddress);
  vMailItem.Subject := 'mymail';
  vMailItem.Body := 'Dear '
  vMailItem.Attachments.Add(path);
  vMailItem.Send;
  VarClear(Outlook);
 end;
```

How can I overcome this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It has to go to the except block. Did you set a breakpoint there to check?

But nevertheless you can prevent the exception from happening:

```
var
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  ClassID: TCLSID;
  Unknown: IUnknown;
begin
  if Succeeded(GetActiveObject(ClassID, nil, Unknown)) then
    OleCheck(Unknown.QueryInterface(IDispatch, Outlook)) else
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
{ ... }
```

Comment: no success ,same error at
 `vMailItem.Recipients.Add(mailaddress);` 

.About the `except` block it goes only after I press break on the same error generated in `try` while debugging,but fails again on     
     `vMailItem.Recipients.Add(mailaddress);` 
.But when using the application the error is generated at `try` block and it goes no further.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But recently I found a workaround. Instead of adding multiple e mail addresses using "**vMailItem.Recipients.Add(mailaddress);**", I used "**vMailItem.To := 'mailID';**". I hope it helps you.

Here is an example:

```
procedure TForm1.SendMailClick(Sender: TObject);
const olMailItem = $00000000;
Var
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  Mail: Variant;
begin
  try
    try
      Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    except
      Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    end;
    Mail := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);

    Mail.To := 'receiver1@xyz.com' + ';' + 'receiver2@xyz.com';

    Mail.Subject := 'your subject';

    Mail.Display; //Mail.Send; if you want to send directly

  Except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
  End;
end;
```